# distill colors of polygons on a map with ggplot2

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, colors

I'm trying to plot the different ways to name a pencil in France on a map with ggplot2. For each of the 96 departments of France, I have one item and a score associated to this item. I have no problem plotting the items according to their departments on a map, but I can't figure out a way to make the colors of each polygons vary according to their associated score. My data is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2645g146q9bmeme/AABIif8cj5V1Wo1TAJxxZ7JKa?dl=0). The code to produce the map is below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(Cairo)

#open data
plotDatafr = read.table("plotDatafr.txt", header=T, sep="\t", quote="", dec=".")
g <- ggplot() + 
geom_polygon(data = plotDatafr, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group, fill=item), alpha=0.8, colour = "black") + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00"), na.value=NA) + 
theme_nothing(legend = TRUE) +
coord_map() #avoid distorsion
ggsave(g, filename = "crayon_euro.png", scale=1) #save for futher use
```

I tried to use the "scale_fill_distiller" command, but with such command I can only plot the properties of a single item, and I loose their given colors, for example:

```
g <- ggplot() + 
geom_polygon(data = plotDatafr, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = score), colour = "black", alpha = 0.8) +
scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Purples", breaks = pretty_breaks(n = 9), labels = percent, direction = 1, "", guide=FALSE) +
guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE, override.aes = list(alpha = 1))) +
theme_nothing(legend = TRUE) + 
coord_map() #avoid distorsion
ggsave(g, filename = "crayon_euro.png", scale=1) #save for futher use
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can make the different my polygons shades varying according to their numerical value? I can't figure a way to combine scale_fill_distiller and scale_fill_manual in the same time.

Comment: can you make a minimal reproducible example for your problem? asking people to download multiple files and install multiple packages seems overkill for a `geom_polygon(aes(fill =))` problem, maybe add the outcome of `dput(plotDatafr)`

Comment: Adding `alpha=score` could be one way to differentiate the different values of `score`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NathanDay - I edited my question, provided the dataset and shortened the code.

Comment: @Haboryme what do you mean by adding `alpha=score`? I tried `scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Transparent", breaks = pretty_breaks(n = 9), labels = percent, direction = 1, "", guide=FALSE) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE, override.aes = list(alpha = "score")))  +  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00"), na.value=NA)` but i got an error message: `Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which will replace the existing scale`

Comment: I meant that instead of having a set `alpha` you could have one that varies  depending on the value of `score` so that you can see the differences according to `item` while also discriminating different scores. `alpha`is set in the `aes() ` of `geom_polygon`. It is not possible to have `fill` set twice as you're trying to do in the above code

Comment: thanks @Haboryme this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

you could use `scale_fill_gradient` instead to adjust `aes(fill)` by `plotDatafr$score`:

```
#open plotting data
plotDatafr = read.table("plotDatafr.txt", header=T, sep="\t", quote="", dec=".")

# make mapping data object
fr <- map_data("france")

# plot
ggplot(fr, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
    geom_polygon(data = plotDatafr, aes(fill=score), alpha=0.8, colour = "black") + 
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "blue", na.value=NA) + 
    coord_map()
```

[image]

`scale_fill_distiller` is designed for discrete data, so you would have to bin `plotDatafr$score` in some way, before using it.

Comment: Thanks @nathan. This is not exactly what I'm trying to achieve: I want the shades of the colors to vary according to score, but I d like to keep the differents categories of color I introduced with "scale_fill_manual".

Comment: The answer given by @Haboryme abive works perfectly! The trick is to set the alpha with "score directly in the `aes()` of `geom_polygon`:

'ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = plotDatafr, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = item, alpha = score), colour = NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7"), name = "", na.value=NA) + 
  coord_map()'

Thanks to you both!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Haboryme above works perfectly! The trick is to set the alpha with "score" directly in the `aes()` of `geom_polygon`, that is to say:

`ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = plotDatafr, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = item, alpha = score), colour = NA) +  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7"), name = "", na.value=NA) + coord_map()`